# SWITCH Function Expressions

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

Currently I've got a switch function expression and i'm reaching limitations within the expression. Is there a max of limitation with using SWITCH? When I add in a fourth expression, this seems to break.

Filtering within Reporting Services

```
=SWITCH(Variables!seconds.Value < 0, "Testing is not required",
Variables!seconds.Value <= 30,"PASS",
Variables!seconds.Value > 30,"FAIL",
Variables!seconds.Value = ""," ")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is with the final expression comparing to a string when the variable seems to be numeric.  I would suspect you could fix your issue with the `IsNothing` function.

```
=SWITCH(IsNothing(Variables!seconds.Value), Nothing,
Variables!seconds.Value < 0, "Testing is not required",
Variables!seconds.Value <= 30,"PASS",
Variables!seconds.Value > 30,"FAIL")
```

Based on the comments, OP prefers to have a `FAIL` result when the field is nothing and he would want to use the following expression.

```
=SWITCH(IsNothing(Variables!seconds.Value) OR Variables!seconds.Value > 30, "FAIL", 
Variables!seconds.Value < 0, "Testing is not required", 
Variables!seconds.Value <= 30,"PASS")
```

Fixing the expression OP posted as a comment...  An `IIF` statement has a conditional, a true condition, and a false condition and should be in the form of `IIF(x=0, true, false)`.  Any additional conditions will give you the error you commented.  In this case, the false condition is another nested `IIF` which would look like the following.

```
=iif(Variables!PAT_ID_Count.Value = 0, "PASS", 
     iif(IsNothing(Variables!Summary.Value), "FAIL","" ))
```

As I've now helped with multiple expressions, I'd like to point out that if you have additional expressions that are generating errors, you should post them as a new question and mark this answer as correct with the checkmark under the arrows to the left.  It seems that I've solved the original problem from your initial question and SO prefers to separate individual issues to curate a library of common problems and solutions.

Comment: Receive a Pass result when there is not seconds value to report. Using the above solution.

Comment: @Diego83 Can you try putting the `IsNothing` conditional first in the switch?

Comment: I get the following :  [BC30588] Omitted argument cannot match a ParamArray parameter.

Comment: Did you remember to remove the comma after the FAIL condition?  That error would relate to an extra comma in the expression.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the string positioning?

Comment: I edited my answer to the expression I'm suggesting you use.

Comment: Just to follow up. This works, it give a blank. However, i'd want to add in a Fail in this case. Is this simply replacing nothing with fail

Comment: You could do that or you could add the two conditionals together.  So the expression would be `=SWITCH(IsNothing(Variables!seconds.Value) OR Variables!seconds.Value > 30, "FAIL", Variables!seconds.Value < 0, "Testing is not required", Variables!seconds.Value <= 30,"PASS")`

Comment: Thanks.. I've got another symptom going on. I've got the following: iif(Variables!Count.Value = 0, "PASS", "FAIL". I've got output that is blank, but this is not posting a FAIL in this case, it give a PASS.

Comment: The following is giving me an error:   =iif(Variables!PAT_ID_Count.Value = 0, "PASS", "FAIL", iif(IsNothing(Variables!Summary.Value), "FAIL","" ))   I'm getting Too many arguments to 'Public Function IIf(Expression As Boolean, TruePart As Object, FalsePart As Object) As Object'.

Comment: @Diego83 I've edited my answer, but I'd prefer if you ask for additional help in a new question if you are having further issues with other expressions.